# Draw and manage a layout with JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm looking for a javascript or VueJs library that I can use for drawing a something simplier than a house layout.
I need this map interactive ( add point, display informations, ....)

Thanks

Comment: Use three.js, go through it's documentation, you'll find everything. https://threejs.org/

Comment: Do you think that's the simplest way to have just a 2D layout ?

Comment: It's the most extensive one with most space for customization, it is also widely supported and used so you'll find more help, tutorials about it. For simple 2D layout you can also look at: https://two.js.org/